# Has anyone tried to use jekyll to generate dashboard pages?

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm using static html pages and incline js to generate dashboard. The backend is go.

However, as number of pages growing, I have to maintain a lot of html pages, and many of the block elements are duplicated.

I'm wondering whether there're some cases to use jekyll to generate dashboard pages, since jekyll can convert pieces of elements into complete htmls? So that I can modify one part and the modification take effect on every html pages that generated.

Are there better framework to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're duplicating elements, then those are the perfect pieces of markup to put into a layout and/or include. That's exactly what those are for.

Each individual page you need can reference a specific layout in its front matter. Includes can be used within the individual pages or within the layouts or both (and can be nested).

The [Jekyll Documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) is ok for this, but to wrap your head around it I find it easiest to look at the documentation together with a few existing [Jekyll templates](http://jekyllthemes.org/) to understand how it all fits together.

Answer (score 0):

after a bit more dig. I found that packages such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) can be used to generate htmls from separate parts.